# I have a laravel API project about store of products

Tags: laravel, api, postman, authorization, token

in my app , user's have to signup and login then they can add ,update or delete products .
now i have created CRUD function in Product Controller and signup/login function in another one .
then i have made routes in API file (look at the photo)[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAUAT.png)
the problem is that when i try to access a store function (in postman) the result is : not authorized.
note: i have logged in properly after trying this and i have copied the given token and pasted it in authorization filed in header (and i have used bearer after token)
can any one help me ? thanks in advance

Comment: which package are you currently using for authentication?

Comment: i use passport ...

Comment: try this reference https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-secure-api-php-laravel-passport

Comment: "bearer after token" Its Bearer <token>

Comment: ya that's true ,the problem was that the letter " b " has to be in upper case in " Bearer " word , i have not thought it as simple as it is .thanks